# Pure JavaScript function to select all element

Tags: javascript

Like jQuery $(selector), i'm writing a custom function in pure JS, The problem is my function select only the first element.

```
function selectall(selector) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    return elements[i];
  }
}
selectall("h2").style.color = "blue";
```

Comment: You're unconditionally returning in a for-loop, which doesn't make sense. What was your intent there? And your function doesn't do anything with the return of `querySelectorAll`. It finds the elements, then does nothing with them.

Comment: In order to achieve what you want to achieve you have to do some tricks with getters and setters. It isn't an easy task. You should use proxies.

Comment: @DAS You wont use jquery for this?

Answer (score 1):

That's unnatural - even jQuery only offers the method [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

It is possible to do so with a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set):

```
function selectall(selector) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var styleProxy = {};
  var cssStyleDeclaration = document.createElement(selector).style;
  for (var prop in cssStyleDeclaration) {
    const PROP = prop;
    Object.defineProperty(styleProxy, PROP, { set: function (value) {
      elements.forEach(function(element) {
        element.style[PROP] = value;
      });
    }});
  }
  return {
    style: styleProxy
  };
}

// Works with most style properties
selectall("h2").style.color = "blue";
selectall("h2").style.fontSize = "10px";
```

Comment: You don't have to, if you use Proxy from ES6.

Comment: Not all browsers support ES6.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=proxy and https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect

Comment: He didn't ask for ES5 strict or something similar. The downvote was because there are polyfills for that small amount of browser that does not give the Proxy object, and your answer is inaccurate or incomplete.

Comment: @lilezek Is my updated answer complete enough to retract your downvote?

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Comment: @araron For sure.

Answer (score 1):

The way to write something that allows you to use the syntax like you do would be something like this:

```js
// First we need a function that returns an object that has prototype
// linkage to some object with getters and setters for style properties,
// when called as a constructor:
function DOMCollection(selector) {
    this.collection = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}


// We'll need an accessor property called 'style' on DOMCollection.prototype,
// to create a scoped reference to 'this' we can access from nested property
// getters and setters:
Object.defineProperty(DOMCollection.prototype, 'style', {


    get() {
        let _DOMCollection = this;
        
        return {

            // We can create a style object with setters for style properties.
            // This setter iterates the array of found elements, and performs
            // the written statement for each element in the collection:
            set color(value) {
                _DOMCollection.collection.forEach((element) => element.style.color = value);
            }
        };
    }
});

// Next, we will have to create a factory function that instantiates
// a new DOMCollection object from the given selector:
function selectAll(selector) {
    return new DOMCollection(selector);
}


// Now we get back a new DOMCollection whose prototype contains a setter
// for the style.color property. You are now able to use the notation
// written in the question:
selectAll('h2').style.color = 'blue';
```

```html
<h2>A heading</h2>
<h2>Another heading</h2>
<h2>Yet another heading</h2>
```

Note that you would have to write a setter explicitly for each style property you'd like to mutate this way. A cleaner option would be to give the final property (*color* in this case) to a function form of style. That is essentially what `$('h2').css('...')` does. As an alternative to the `defineProperty` statement above you can do:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} keyValues
 */
DOMCollection.prototype.style = function(keyValues) {

    // Iterate all keys in given style object:
    Object.keys(keyValues).forEach((key) => {

        let value = keyValues[key];

        // Then for each style, apply it to each element in this.collection:
        this.collection.forEach((element) => {
            element.style[key] = value;
        })

    })
};
```

Now you would be able to write code similar to `$.css()`, with as many style definitions as you wish:

```
selectAll('h2').style({
    color: 'blue',
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    // .. as many as you wish
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve your goal like this.

```js
function changeColor(selector,style,value){
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  divs.forEach(function(elem){
    elem.style[style] = value;
  });
}

changeColor("h2","color","blue");
//changeColor("h2","color","red");
```

```html
<h3>test1</h3>
<h2>test2</h2>
<h2>test3</h2>
```

You could write function like this

```
function changeColor(selector){
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  divs.forEach(function(elem){
    elem.style.color = "blue";
  });
}

changeColor("h2");
```

Or you can make a Array prototype of your.

```js
function changeColor(selector){
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var elems = [];
  divs.forEach(function(elem){
    elems.push(elem);
  });
  return elems;
}

Array.prototype.mystyle = function(style,value){
  for(var i=0; i<this.length ; i++){
    this[i].style[style] = value;
  }
}

changeColor("h2").mystyle("color","blue");
```

```html
<h3>test1</h3>
<h2>test2</h2>
<h2>test3</h2>
```

Comment: He wants to achieve jQuery-like chaining.

Comment: @lilezek Frankly, with a goal like that, it's probably best to just use jQuery. (I may or may not have been through this myself :p)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I agree, but if the OP wants jQuery-like chaining, this is not a solution. By the way, there must be Proxy examples of chaining anywhere.

Comment: And why he use jquery tag then...?

Comment: @lilezek : I didn't find that he want chaining I thought he just want to select and make changes color in each objects here `H2`.

Comment: @SilverSurfer because he wants to achieve jQuery-like chaining.

Comment: @lilezek : where you found this text ? `wants to achieve jQuery-like chaining` ?

Comment: @lilezek : as OP is not responding we should not reading others mind that what he want to do.Right ?